# how to read from middle of text file

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream

I am writing a program that reads from two files ("joke.text"and"punchline.txt") there is "garbage" in the punchline file and i cant figure out how to read just the line i want. Please help. Also, I am using Visual Studios

this is what I have:

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <fstream>
   #include <string>
   using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream jokeFile;
    string data;
    char input;
    cout << "opening the file... \n";
    jokeFile.open("joke.txt", ios::in);

    if (jokeFile.is_open())
    {
        getline(jokeFile, data);

        while (jokeFile )
        {
            cout << data <<endl;
            getline(jokeFile, data);
        }

        jokeFile.close();

    } 
    else
    {
        cout << "ERROR: could not open that file\n";
    }


    cout << "would like you see the punchline? (Y/N) \n";
    cin >> input;

/*  if ( input == 'N' || 'n')
    {
        cout << "Ok, keep guessing\n";


    }*/

     if (input == 'Y' || 'y')
    {

        jokeFile.open("punchline.txt", ios::in);

        if (jokeFile.is_open())
        {
            //getline(jokeFile, data, '\n');

            while (jokeFile)
            {

                cout << data; 
                getline(jokeFile, data, '\n');

            }

            jokeFile.close();
        }

        else
        {

            cout << "ERROR: could not open the file\n";
        }
    }


    /*{
        cout << "invalid response, try again\n";
    }*/




    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the output:

```
opening the file... 
Two men who work together in a facory were talking.
"I know how to get some time off," said one.
"How are you going to do that?" asked the other.
"Watch," he said, and climbed a ladder to the ceiling.
The foreman asked what he was doing up there,
and the man replied. "I'm a lightbulb."
"I think you need some time off," the foreman
said, and the first man walked out of the 
factory. After a moment, the second man followed 
him. "Where do you think you're going?" 
the foreman shouted.


would like you see the punchline? (Y/N) 
y
asdasdasdasdasdfdssdfdsaasdfdssfddsfdsasdsad"I can't work in the dark, " he said.
```

Comment: How does the program know which line it wants? (Or how should it know?)

Comment: If you know exactly what line you want to read you can call `fseek()` which will change the file pointer to the line you want. After that you could call `getline()`

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

1. You **know** the position you wish to seek to.  If so, then see the seek functions here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/
2. You **do not** know the position you wish to seek to, but you know what the garbage "looks like", in which case you'll need to read it and parse it till you've read past it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fseek` in order to get the size of the file, than divide it to half, and start reading from half with `fseek` again.

`int fseek(FILE *stream, long int offset, int whence)`

**Example:** (Have not been tested)

```
int size = fseek(jokeFile, 0, SEEK_END);
fseek(jokeFile, size/2.0, SEEK_SET);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is misleading for the problem you're presenting. It looks like your program is trying to output all of the jokefile.txt, prompt the user, then output all of the punchline.txt file. The garbage output before the punch line must be the gibberish returned to the 'data' string when the EOF is reached on jokefile.txt. And your first read of punchline.txt is commented out, so the cout in that loop dumps the garbage before reading and outputing the punch line.